# Sitecore Content Editor - Make the Publish Button "Approve and Publish"?

Tags: asp.net, workflow, sitecore, publishing, content-editor

Problem: Within the Content Editor, our web editors with the privileges to edit content as well as publish that content are often forgetting to go to Edit>Approve and Publish, instead they are just saving and trying to press the publish button which publishes to master, but not the live production server. I understand that approve and publish puts the page into the final workflow step, and (atleast on our servers) the publish button does not. I'm wondering if the Publish button can be changed to function as 'Approve and Publish' and whether that will cause any issues for people who have editor privileges but not publishing privileges.

Along those same lines, our admins can save and publish with the publish button without approving by using Edit>Approve and Publish, but they cannot do this with new pages. New pages have to be approved and published once and from that point on they can simply save and then publish with publish button and the content goes live. Is there any way to bypass that initial 'Approve and Publish' step for admins?

I have some experience working in the core as well as editing the workflow, but I apologize if this is a really simple problem, or if I'm missing the point of the way our workflow is setup. I also considered creating an Approve button and putting it next to edit, so that our editors were more likely to remember that step, but I couldn't find an approve command to associate with the new button. I would love some feedback from Sitecore veterans.

Comment: I think making a custom command, that executes that workflow command and wiring it up to a new button would be good.  That way you still have a stock publish option for folks who don't want to "accidentally" approve.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to do, but I haven't been able to determine the workflow command to approve and publish to add to that button.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the behavior of the publish button is not recommeded and will just end up confusing everyone.  Also adding a new button will just lead to more confusion about which button your editors should be using.

Since your editors have to use workflow, they probably don't need access to the standard publish button.  Simply removing them from the Sitecore Client Publishing role will make it so they can't see the publish button and therefore have to use the workflow command.

If workflow is turned on, a new version of an item will always be put into the first step of that workflow.  You could change that behavior with a handler for the version:added event.  If you are only concerned about new items, a processor for the uiAddFromTemplate pipeline could also be used.  However, I don't recommend changing this behavior at all.  For that matter, I don't recommend using full admin users for content editing at all since you will lose the versioning of your content items.  Admin users should be used for administration, not content editing.

Comment: Good answer :-)    But just to add something meaningful to this comment; it is my experience that trying to alter Sitecore behaviour to compensate for user shortcomings is a bad idea. Apply more training and drilling instead.

Comment: In this case, it isn't user shortcomings. Many of our web editors are given Editor/Approver roles and they simply don't need to approve their own content. So in a perfect world the main workflow would default to approved and editors could simply save and then after previewing, publish. The problem is that a handful of divisions do use separate editors and approvers, so to maintain the current workflow, I'm just looking to create a new publish button for editor/approvers and using the regular publish button for those divisions that still do that separately.

Comment: And yes, we could remove the publish button entirely, but there are two issues there. One, a handful of items and templates don't have defined workflows. Two, we currently have over 400 trained editors and if I remove the publish button entirely, many editors are going to be very confused. So although I understand that changing the functionality of the publish button is not recommended, in this case I think it's justified to make a new publish button that can approve and publish. I'm open to other ideas if you have them.

Comment: The recommended solution for your Editor/Approvers would be to add an aditional workflow command that skips the intermediate workflow steps and goes directly to the final step and executes the auto-publish action.  Then, you can apply security to that command so it can only be used by the appropriate users.

Comment: We have a Workflow command that approves into the final workflow step and then auto-publishes as you suggest called "Approve and Publish", but how do we change the chunk for the button itself so that it initiates that particular workflow command? Currently, our publish button chunk has a click field of item:publishnow, but that doesn't do the same thing as the "Approve and Publish" workflow command which is initiated in the edit drop down. Is there any way to edit the Pubish chunk (or a duplicate of that chunk, more precisely) to initiate a Workflow command?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my last comment.  I do not recommend changing the default publish button or adding duplicate of it.  I was saying that you could set up an additional workflow command for your admin users so that they can skip over the intermediate steps of the workflow.